# NextJS Responsive Image to Parent Div

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css

I am trying to figure out a weird styling bug where I have a NextJS Image component inside a resizeable window that loads the first image in a loop to a good size, but when I click a button to shuffle to the next image it loads the image and those that follow at 16px x 9px. I can't seem to figure out if there is a class I should be applying at the Image level or parent divs to correct this behavior. I'm using TailwindCSS to style my components.

[image: right]

[image: wrong]

**Here is my code:**

```
<Rnd
  className={`window ${
    imageViewerWindowOpen ? 'display' : 'hidden !important'
  } z-10`}
  minHeight={300}
  minWidth={300}
  maxHeight={500}
  maxWidth={500}
  style={{
    display: `${imageViewerWindowOpen ? 'hidden' : 'hidden'}`,
  }}
  bounds="window"
  onResizeStart={(e, dir, ref) => {
    setWindowWidth(ref.style.width);
    setWindowHeight(ref.style.height);
  }}
  onResizeStop={(e, direction, ref, delta, position) => {
    setWindowWidth(ref.style.width);
    setWindowHeight(ref.style.height);
  }}
  cancel=".title-bar-controls"
>
  <div className="title-bar">
    <div className="title-bar-text">Image Viewer</div>
    <div className="title-bar-controls">
      <button aria-label="Minimize"></button>
      <button aria-label="Maximize"></button>
      <button
        aria-label="Close"
        onClick={() => {
          imageViewerState(false);
        }}
      ></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div className={`window-body w-${windowWidth} h-${windowHeight}`}>
    <div className="flex justify-center mt-4 space-x-4 mb-5">
      <button onClick={handlePreviousImage} className="pr-2">
        Previous Image
      </button>
      <button onClick={handleNextImage}>Next Image</button>
    </div>
    <Image
      src={`/images/${currentImage.image_id}`}
      width={0}
      height={0}
      style={{
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
      }}
      alt="Images"
    />
  </div>
</Rnd>
```

**With the main components:**

```
<div className={`window-body w-${windowWidth} h-${windowHeight}`}>
  <div className="flex justify-center mt-4 space-x-4 mb-5">
    <button onClick={handlePreviousImage} className="pr-2">
      Previous Image
    </button>
    <button onClick={handleNextImage}>Next Image</button>
  </div>
  <Image
    src={`/images/${currentImage.image_id}`}
    width={0}
    height={0}
    style={{
      width: 'auto',
      height: 'auto',
    }}
    alt="Images"
  />
</div>
```